# Unable to load .mozilla during installation sometimes (ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: firefox, home-directory, hidden-files

I am unable to see `.Mozilla` in `/home/mvrp` directory (the name I have given who am I during installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) some times after installation.  when I could see it in `/home/mvrp` directory I am unable to copy it into a cd/dvd.

Can some one advise me what I have to do to have `.Mozilla` in `/home/mvrp` directory always?

Comment: .mozilla is a hidden folder, same as anything that begins with a dot. Press ctrl-h to show hidden files, or remove the dot to permanently unhide it.

Comment: I wouldn't fiddle with that folder's name, location, or hidden status. Note that things in Linux are case-sensitive so .mozilla != .Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `.mozilla` rather than `.Mozilla`. [As vasa1 says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339574/unable-to-load-mozilla-during-installation-sometimes-ubuntu-12-04-lts#comment433297_339574), filenames in Ubuntu are generally [case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). The `.mozilla` subfolder of your home folder contains your Firefox profile. (*If you really do have `.Mozilla` with a capital `M`*, please let us know, and provide more details about what this folder is and what you're trying to accomplish.)

As [mikewhatever says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339574/unable-to-load-mozilla-during-installation-sometimes-ubuntu-12-04-lts#comment433272_339574), files and folders whose names start with a `.` are hidden by default. To show them, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or click *View* **>** *Show Hidden Files*. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut works in most file browsers, and also typically works in Open File (and Save File, Export To, Select File, etc.) dialog boxes.

To copy your `.mozilla` folder somewhere else, just show hidden files as explained above, and copy it as usual.

If you're burning it to a CD/DVD/BluRay using Brasero, you do it essentially the same way. But you have two options. You can drag it in from a file browser window, or you can click the **+** to add files and select it.

[image: Select Files dialog box in Brasero, showing hidden files]
<sup>**When the *Select Files* dialog box appears, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, just as you would in a file browser window.**</sup>

If you rename `.mozilla` so it doesn't start with a `.`, then it will always be shown, **but it will not be found by Firefox**. So if you prefer, you can rename the backed-up copy. But when you restore it, it will need to start with the `.` to be recognized as the folder that contains your Firefox profile.